# Weird exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException I/O Java

Tags: java, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I have this error when I am trying to read the file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \src\product.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at dao.Inventory.readFile(Inventory.java:30)
at view.InventoryView.init(InventoryView.java:33)
at view.InventoryView.<init>(InventoryView.java:21)
at view.InventoryView.main(InventoryView.java:211)
```

But the thing is, I have the product.txt in my src folder.

My code is the following:

```
  public void readFile() throws IOException {
            // input file must be supplied in the first argument
            InputStream istream;
                    File inputFile = new File("\\src\\product.txt");
                    istream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

                    BufferedReader lineReader;
                lineReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
                    String line;

                        while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {

                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");

                // String tmp = tokens.nextToken();
                // System.out.println("token " + tmp);
                ActionProduct p = new ActionProduct();
                prodlist.add(p);
                String category = p.getCategory();
                category = tokens.nextToken();
                System.out.println("got category " +category);

                int item = p.getItem();
                item = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());

                String name = p.getName();
                System.out.println("got name " +name);

                double price = p.getPrice();
                price = Double.parseDouble(tokens.nextToken());

                int units = p.getUnits();
                units = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
            }
        }
```

I don't think anything is wrong with my code. Also, I saw a similar post about a hidden extension like FILE.TXT.TXT, how would you show a hidden extension in MacOSX?? Any suggestions? (Would there be any other problem besides the hidden extension issue?)

Comment: You should have `src\\product.txt` as the path if your file is in `src` folder.

Comment: Try `File inputFile = new File("./src/product.txt");` instead.

Comment: Or File inputFile = new File("src\\product.txt");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/src/product.txt` is an absolute path, so the program will try to find the file in the src folder of your root path (/). Use `src/product.txt` so the program will use this as a relative path.

Comment: +1 You should use \\ instead of \, or even better, use `/` for independent operating system.

Comment: i'm new in java and facing same problem ,what if the file in target not src? i tried all of this but still

Comment: @user3188912 then use the absolute path of the file. If you're on windows, then it will be "C:\\path\\to\\your\\file.ext", if you're on *-nix systems then it will be "/path/to/your/file.ext".

Answer (score 1):

It's possible (most likely?) that your Java code is not executing inside the parent folder of src, but instead inside a 'class' or a 'bin' folder with the compiled java .class files.

Assuming that 'src' and 'bin' are in the same directory, you could try `..\\src\\product.txt`

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Answer (score 1):

1. As other commenters stated, the path is absolute and points to
   \src\product.txt which is (hopefully) not where
   your sources are stored.
2. The path separator should be set in an OS-independent manner using
       the System.getProperty("path.separator") property. On a Unix system, you'll have trouble with hard coded backslashes as path separators. Keep it portable!

> ```
> String pathSeparator = System.getProperty("path.separator");
> String filePath = "." + pathSeparator + "src" + pathSeparator + "product.txt";
> File file = new File(filePath);
> ```

or better yet:

```
// this could reside in a non-instantiable helper class somewhere in your project
public static String getRelativePath(String... pathElements) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(".");
    for (String pathElement : pathElements) {
        builder.append(System.getProperty("path.separator");
        builder.append(pathElement);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

// this is where your code needs a path
...
new File(getRelativePath("src", "product.txt");
...
```