# How to read a File using FileInputStream compatible in all OS

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I am having a file and i need to read it using FileInputStream in java.
I need to give the path which should be readable in all OS.
Now i have given

```
(new FileInputStream("..\\config.properties"));
```

which is a windows readable format
But this is a non readable in Unix.

Is there any way common for all OS.

Comment: i don't know if this would help or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java

Comment: Refer to these already answered questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092260/fileinputstream-how-to-take-a-path-directly-without-adding-escape-characters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953328/weird-exception-in-thread-main-java-io-filenotfoundexception-i-o-java

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. For standalone classes you can use:

   ```
    new FileInputStream("../config.properties")
   ```
2. For classes in JAR file you can use:

   ```
   InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../config.properties");
   ```

This should help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Instead of

```
new FileInputStream("..\\config.properties")
```

This should work everywhere

```
new FileInputStream("../config.properties")
```

Or you could use

new FileInputStream(".." + java.io.File.separator + "config.properties")

Comment: Hi Elliott, if am giving this class inside a jar will this work?

Comment: That's not a class, it's a text file. What are you asking?

Comment: `config.properties` is a text file. This is how you access a File on your filesystem, not how you access a properties file in a JAR file.